# How to start pig with -t ColumnMapKeyPrune on aws emr

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-emr

In my pig script i want file name with each record for some further processing so i used -tagFile option. Now after using -tagFile option, the column names were getting un aligned so i used below command to get only required columns after referring this blog : http://www.webopius.com/content/764/resolved-apache-pig-with-tagsource-tagfile-option-generates-incorrect-columns

> pig -x mapreduce -t ColumnMapKeyPrune

Now i want to run the script on **AWS EMR** but i am not sure how to enable this -t ColumnMapKeyPrune option on EMR Pig.?

I am using AWS CLI to create aws cluster and submit jobs.
Any pointer for how to enable -t ColumnMapKeyPrune on EMR Pig.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I need to add below line in pig script:

```
set pig.optimizer.rules.disabled 'ColumnMapKeyPrune';
```